# AJAX is only getting data from last form in loop (Django)

Tags: django, ajax, forms, ajaxform

I have a for loop that creates a number of forms on the page. I want to be able to submit these forms to another page without refresh using AJAX, however no matter which form I submit it only ever shows the value for the very last form.

HTML code

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    <form class = "f_form" id="f_form" name = "myForm" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="add">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.add',function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var element = $(this);

          $.ajax({
              url: '{% url "webscraper-favorited" %}',
              method: 'post',
              data:element.parent('.f_form').serialize(),
              success: function(data){
                  $('#message').html(data);
              }
          });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

views.py

```
def favorited(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        favorited = request.POST.get('favorited')
        favorites.append(favorited)
        print(favorited)
    context = {
        'favorites' : favorites,
    }
    return render(request, 'webscraper/favorited.html', context)
```

Right now the script is outside of the for loop but I previously tried putting it in the for loop as well. Instead of binding the script to the submit button I also tried binding it to the form id. That yielded the same result from my attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same `id` for multiple forms in your loop. HTML `id` attributes must be unique within a document. When you use `$('#f_form')` in your jQuery code, it only selects the first form with that `id`.

Modify your HTML and jQuery code to use class selectors instead of `id` for the forms. Here's an updated version:

HTML code:

```html
{% for post in post_list %}
    <form class="f_form" name="myForm" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="add">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

jQuery code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('submit', '.f_form', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url "webscraper-favorited" %}',
                method: 'post',
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#message').html(data);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```